# Choose parameters to make a harmonic function

Tags: harmonic-functions

Let $B(0;1)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^N ;|x|\leq 1\}$,  the ball of $\mathbb{R}^N$ equipped with the euclidian scalar product 
$$x \cdot y=x_1y_1+...+x_Ny_N,\ \ \ x=(x_1,...,x_N),\ \ y=(y_1,...,y_N)\ \ \ |x|=\sqrt{x\cdot x}.$$
Let $\alpha\mbox{ , } \beta \mbox{ two real numbers, } \alpha\geq 0\mbox{ , } a \in \partial B(0,1)$ fix.
$$h(x)=\log\left((1-x\cdot a)^{\alpha}+|x-a|^{\beta}\right)$$
Can we find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $h$ is harmonic in $B(0,1)$?

Comment: [This was also posted to MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/156486/1916). Please note that [crossposting between SE sites is highly frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068) - try one site first, and if you don't get a satisfactory response, ask a moderator to **migrate** the question to a different site. If you insist on posting in many sites, at least provide links to the other posts - as you can imagine, it would be frustrating for someone to put time into answering your question here, only to find out that you'd already gotten an answer elsewhere.

Comment: Surely _harmonic_ signifies that $\Delta_x h = 0$, not that $\Delta_x h = $ the definition of Laplacian of $h$.

Comment: Would $\alpha=\beta=0$ do?

Comment: No, it will be constant so its not important case

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, choose a unit vector $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ with components
$a_1=1$, $a_j=0\;\,\forall\,j\geqslant 2$.  This may be done by rotation $\,y=Sx\,$ with an orthogonal matrix $S$ such that $(Sa)_1=1$, $(Sa)_j=0\;\,\forall\,j
\geqslant 2$.  A rather trivial check shows that function
$$
h(x)=\ln\Bigl(1-x_1+\sqrt{(1-x_1)^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}\Bigr)
$$
is harmonic inside a unit ball $\,|x|<1\,$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, 
*i.e.*,  $\,\alpha=\beta=1\,$ is the answer to the question for space dimension 
$n=3$.  For all $n\geqslant 2$,  there are no other 
$\,\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$  with nonconstant harmonic $h$.  
Restriction $\,\alpha\geqslant 0\,$ proves absolutely unimportant.

Interestingly enough, all more or less sophisticated approaches fail to give 
a complete answer to the question. Thus conformal mappings are accompanied by restriction $n=2$ on space dimension, a maximum principle for a subharmonic 
function $|\nabla\,h|^2$ works very nice with any $\,n\geqslant 2\,$ but only for 
$\,\alpha=0\,$ and $\,\beta>0\,$, and so on, so on, so on.  Instead, absolutely 
unsophisticated, naive Taylor expansion around the origin $\,x=0\,$ 
gives a complete answer to the question  for all required values of 
$n\geqslant 2$, $\,\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}\,$ along with a bonus option 
$\,\alpha<0\,$ in addition.  The Taylor series
$$
h(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P_k(x), \quad x\in B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,\colon\,|x|<1\},
$$
is absolutely convergent inside the unit ball $B$, with homogeneous polynomials 
$\,P_k\,$ of degree $k$ being harmonic for any $k\geqslant 0$, *i.e.*,
$$
\Delta\,P_k(x)=0,\quad \forall\, x\in B\;\Rightarrow\;\forall\, x\in \mathbb{R}^n\;\;
\forall\, k\geqslant 0. 
$$
To establish that either $\,\alpha=\beta=0\,$ or $\,\alpha=\beta=1\,$, it suffices to examine just three cases of $\,k=2,3,4\,$, *i.e.*, examine the implications of identities
$$
\Delta\,P_2(x)=\Delta\,P_3(x)=\Delta\,P_4(x)=0\quad \forall\, x\in\mathbb{R}^n.
\tag{$\ast$}
$$
To find polynomials $\,\Delta P_k(x)\,$, one can apply the Taylor series
expansion to the function
$$
g(x_1,r)=\ln\biggl((1-x_1)^{\alpha}+\bigl(1-2x_1+x_1^2+r^2\bigr)^{\beta/2}\biggr)
$$
with respect to variables $x_1$ and $r$, applying herewith the Laplace operator
in the form
$$
\Delta =\frac{\partial^2\,}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2\,}{\partial r^2}+
\frac{n-2}{r}\!\cdot\!\frac{\partial\,}{\partial r}\,,
$$
and substituting thereafter $\,r=|x'|^2$, $x'\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.  Running the available symbolic calculations software readily reduces the identities $\,(\ast)\,$ to four algebraic equations, the three of which:
$$
\begin{gather}
\alpha^2-2\alpha\beta+\beta^2+2\beta n-2\alpha-4\beta=0, \\
\alpha\beta n-\beta^2 n+3\alpha^2-7\alpha\beta+4\beta^2+4\beta n-4\alpha-8\beta=0,\\
\beta(\beta n+5\alpha-4\beta-4n+8)=0,
\end{gather}
$$
are more than enough to show that either $\,\alpha=\beta=0\,$ or 
$\,\alpha=\beta=1\,$.